# Why do I get "Null" in MySQL database? Flash pro cs6

Tags: php, flash, flash-cs6

I'm trying to update a flash movie quiz that records names and question answers - I did not write the original application. The quiz works, except that it replaces the name with null when recording data. All the other records work fine. I have deleted out the `res2 - res12` just to shorten it up, they all work well.

- Im using Flash Pro CS6
- The code is in AS3

Thanks in advance for any light you can shed on this.

---

From Name input page of the quiz. `participname` is the text field input:

```
stop();

btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,function():void {
    var Name:String=participname.text.toString();
    gotoAndPlay(3);
});
```

From the last page of the quiz

sendData();
function sendData(){
    var messages:URLRequest = new URLRequest("./insertresult.php")
    messages.method = URLRequestMethod.POST

```
var posts:URLVariables = new URLVariables()
posts.Name = Name
posts.DateCurrent = dtFormatted
posts.Res01 = res01

messages.data = posts
trace(posts);

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader()
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT
// loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, dataOnLoad)
loader.load(messages)

trace(messages);
```

From the insertresult.php:

```
<?php
    //Capture data from $_POST array
    $name = $_POST['Name'];
    $date = $_POST['DateCurrent'];
    $res1 = $_POST['Res01'];


    /* if(!$name ) {
        echo "no input using default values <br>";
        $name = 'deleteme';
    }*/

    $connect = mysql_connect("mydatabase");
    mysql_select_db ("PAlogindatabase", $connect);
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT into rhymeoddity1 (name,date,res1) values ('$name','$date','$res1')");

    if($result) echo "writing=Ok&";
    else echo "writing=Error";
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: just do a print_r($_POST) in your server script and check what you get

Comment: that php code is vulnerable to SQL injection. do as @h2ooooooo says or it's very insecure

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that the actionscript is actually reading and setting the Name properly before posting the data?

Comment: Yes checked it and its not, i put a dynamic box on the second page and im getting NULL :(

Comment: That then is your problem, you need to figure out how to read data from the dynamic box, after there has been some input into it. This is no longer a PHP issue, it is a flash issue.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted out the problem, i believe that this bit of the code was hiding away the var myname

stop();

btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,function():void {

var myname:String=participname.text.toString();

gotoAndPlay(3);

}

);

i have replaced this with this and it is working fine now.

stop();

var myname:String = "";

btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,function():void {

myname = participname.text;

gotoAndPlay(3);

}

);

If someone can explain what the difference is so i can understand